# How can I map this polymorphism in Hibernate, using XML, without creating extra parent tables?

Tags: hibernate, uuid, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map a tree of POJOs in Hibernate so that I can (a) concisely use UUIDs for primary keys everywhere and (b) externally impose set-like relationships between otherwise unrelated tables.  This seems to work great using annotations, but for the life of me I can't get it to work the same way using HBM XML mapping.

For example, given the following (abbreviated) classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Unique {
    private String uuid;
}

@Entity
public class Relationship extends Unique {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Unique> members;
}

@Entity
public class Activity extends Unique {
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class AssociatedXML extends Unique {
    @Lob
    private String xml;
}
```

...easy peasy.  When I run hbm2ddl it creates the tables `Relationship`, `Relationship_Unique`, `Activity`, and `AssociatedXML`.  Queries like the following HQL seem to work great:

```
session.createQuery("select xml "
    + "from AssociatedXML as xml, Relationship as rel "
    + "left join rel.members as m "
    + "where m.uuid = :uuid").setString("uuid", activity.getUuid());
```

Meanwhile, I am trying to move to XML configuration.  The POJOs are being generated from an XML schema.  Since the source is generated, I am trying to avoid hand-editing it to add the annotations.

I have tried every XML configuration I can think of (as well as fooling with the output of `<hbm2hbmxml/>` in the Hibernate tools). I can't come up with a configuration that doesn't *either* create an additional `Unique` parent table involving an extra join, *or* fail in the session factory with the error:

> Association references unmapped class: Unique

Does anybody have a suggestion as to what my XML config files should look like?  Or am I going down a bad path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something like this:

```
<class name="Unique" abstract = "true">
    <id name="uuid" />

    <union-subclass name="Relationship">
        <set name="members" table = "Relationship_Unique" >
            <key />
            <many-to-many class = "Unique" unique="true"/>
        </set>
    </union-subclass>

    <union-subclass name="Activity">
        <property name = "name" />
    </union-subclass>

    <union-subclass name="AssociaXML">
        <property name = "xml" />
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```

**See also:**

- [8.3.1. One-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join)
- [10.1.5. Table per concrete class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete)

Comment: Aha!  That creates the exact same tables as the annotations, and passes the same query tests.  Merry Christmas (or Kwanzaa or Festivus or whatever)!